# Changing content based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sticky

I am trying to build a `Showcase` component, similar to [the one seen here](https://fleet.postmates.com/fleet-app/), where the user cycles through different content as they scroll:

[image]

I'm making the section fixed by using some CSS:

```
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
}

.top-0 {
  top: 0;
}
```

Applied to my HTML:

```
  <section
    ref={(r) => this.ref = r}
    className={`vh-500 bg-near-white z-max pv6-ns pv3 bg-near-white min-vh-100
    ...
    `}>
    <div className='sticky top-0 vh-100'>
```

Using the `ref` on my HTML element, I work out the area where the `Showcase` component is sticky by seeing the `scrollY` is relation to the top and bottom of the component itself:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.ref) {
      this.setState(
        {
          firstThreshold: this.ref.getBoundingClientRect().top,
          secondThreshold: window.innerHeight * amount
        },
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        () => console.log(this.state, "state")
      );
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }
```

Then in my `handleScroll()` function I detect when we're scrolling through the `Showcase` component:

```
// if we're scrolling through the Showcase component
if (scrollY >= firstThreshold && scrollY <= secondThreshold) {
...
}
```

Now here's the bit I'm lost with:

I get the height of the Component by multiplying the viewport height with the amount of chapters of a story I want to display in my component:

```
const chapters = [
  {
    content: 'Signs up',
    title: '',
  },
  {
    content: 'Receives request',
    title: '',
  },
  {
    content: 'Gets a shit, rude requests from a person with 0 rating',
    title: '',
  },
  {
    content: 'Blocks them',
    title: '',
  },
  {
    content: 'Gets a nice request from a person who’s rated 5 stars',
    title: '',
  },
  {
    content: 'They agree on terms and accept the request',
    title: '',
  },
  {
    content: 'Time elapses',
    title: '',
  },
  {
    content: 'Thanks them for the time, gives them 5 stars',
    title: '',
  },
]

const amount = chapters.length
```

And in my `handleScroll()` function I'm trying to work out which chapter to show as the user scrolls, but I'm not sure how to get there. Here's what I have right now:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log(i, "i");
    if (scrollY >= (firstThreshold + sectionThreshold) * i) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      console.log(sectionThreshold * i, "sectionThreshold * i");
      this.setState({ currentChapter: i }, () => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.log(
          `scrolling inside section: ${this.state.currentChapter}`
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

What I am trying to achieve:

- Display each chapter as the user scrolls through the page

How do I do this?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-frost-x3jsn)

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to figure it out, I think I was just overthinking it before. Basically inside of the `handleScroll(e)` you get the height of each section:

First, get the height of the chapters by dividing the `chapterAmount` by the `componentHeight` and push the results into an array:

```
const chapterHeights = [];
for (let index = 0; index < chapters.length; index++) {
  const chapterHeight = componentHeight / chapterAmount;
  chapterHeights.push(chapterHeight * index);
}
```

Then loop through `chapterHeights` array and compare it to the scroll position, then set the state of the `title` and `content` which will be rendered in the view.

```
for (let index = 0; index < chapterHeights.length; index++) {
  // console.log(chapterHeights[index], "chapterHeights[index]");
  const chapterLength = chapterHeights[index];

  if (scrollY >= chapterLength) {
    this.setState({
      title: chapters[index].title,
      content: chapters[index].content,
    })
  }
}
```

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-frost-x3jsn)